# Can I apply an independent test t on two sets of 30 samples each , even of the normality test fails

Tags: statistics

In the link 
[t-Test](http://pytolearn.csd.auth.gr/d1-hyptest/12/ttest-indep.html")
 there is a nice explanation about the use of the t-test and how to observe the assumptions of the test: normality and equal variance. If the normality check fails (Shapiro test), it recommends to use the Mann-Whitney U test. However it also says " before turning to non-parametric controls you should consult a statistician. It might be the case that your sample data is large enough to apply parametric t-test although the normality criterion is violated"

I would like to know if 30 is large enough or I will have to go with the  Mann-Whitney U test?

Comment: usually, at about 40 observations, you can go with a t-test. This is a rule of thumb, but in small samples (like 30), a t-test can be problematic. I would not trust a t-test with n=30 much. How about trying both?

Comment: I recommend you search the Cross Validated site, as there is quite a few related Q&A's there, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/t-test-for-non-normal-when-n50.  You can search for the t-test tag there.